# How large can i make a Single Port RAM in VHDL on the Nexys A7?

Tags: memory, vhdl, fpga, ram

I am making a project and reading files from an SD card to a RAM where reading and writing to RAM are asynchronous. The project is written in vhdl.
I was wondering if i can make the implementation so that the RAM in the mudule is an array with the size of 150.000 where each entry is a std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)

Basically if i can do this:
`
type RAM is array (integer range <>)of std_logic_vector (DATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);

`
Or is that a problem for the memory?
I haven’t found an answer online about it
Thank you in advance

I haven’t tried it yet , but i read online that it might appear like it’s working fine and generating a bitstream in vivado yet internally something could go wrong and i was just hoping to get more educated on the matter / to understand how memory assignment functions in this kind of scenario

Answer (score 2):

- The Nexys A7 uses the XC7A100T part.
- The part has 270 18K by 1-bit BRAMS.
- BRAM's are configurable as 2K by 9-bits (not configurable as by 8-bits).
- 2K [9-bit locations/BRAM] times 270 [BRAM]  = 540K [9-bit locations]

**The maximum theoretical 8-bit BRAM size is 540K.**

**Yes, a 150K BRAM array of 8-bit values will fit in BRAM on named board's FPGA.**

References for these calculations and for learning about memories in FPGA:
[nexys-a7](https://digilent.com/shop/nexys-a7-fpga-trainer-board-recommended-for-ece-curriculum/)

[7-series-product-selection-guide](https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/selection-guides/7-series-product-selection-guide.pdf)

[ug473_7-Series_Memory_Resources](https://docs.xilinx.com/v/u/en-US/ug473_7Series_Memory_Resources)

[ug901-vivado-synthesis](https://www.xilinx.com/content/dam/xilinx/support/documents/sw_manuals/xilinx2021_2/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf)

Specifically, see the vivado-synthesis guide section 'RAM HDL Coding Techniques' for a VHDL memory coding template.